# Nesting multiple same type class inside one parent

Tags: less, lesscss-resources

I want to create classes like below:

```
.colored{
     &{
          .red{background-color:red;}
          .blue{background-color:blue;}
          .gray{background-color:gray;}
      }
}
```

and it is not working but if I write like this:

```
.colored{
          &.red{
              background-color:red;
          }
          &.blue{
              background-color:blue;
          }
          &.gray{
              background-color:gray;
          }
}
```

then it works. Are there any reasons why the first version does not work as expected?

Answer (score 3):

**Reason:**

It is because of the way nesting works (and is supposed to work) in Less. When you nest a selector under another selector, the inner selector is considered as applicable for an element which is a child of the element represented by the outer selector.

The below is code

```
.colored{
    &{
        .red{background-color:red;}
        .blue{background-color:blue;}
        .gray{background-color:gray;}
    }
}
```

is equivalent to the following (because `&` will be replaced by the parent selector which is `.colored`)

```
.colored{
    .red{background-color:red;}
    .blue{background-color:blue;}
    .gray{background-color:gray;}
}
```

Now as I mentioned earlier, this would compile to `.colored .red`, `.colored .blue`, `.colored .gray` (note the space between the selectors).

On the other hand when you insert the `&` immediately before `.red`, .`blue`, .`gray`, it means that the parent selector and the nested selector apply to the same element (and not a child). The selectors that it would output is `.colored.red`, `.colored.blue`, `.colored.gray` (note that there is no space).

---

**Solution:**

This is the same code as in your question and it is the ***recommended solution***. I am posting it again in the answer only to make it complete.

```
.colored{
    &.red{
        background-color:red;
    }
    &.blue{
        background-color:blue;
    }
    &.gray{
        background-color:gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: i if i write as you say i must use colored class in parent element like this
    <span class="colored>
        <span class="red"></span>
    </span>
but i do not want it. i want to use like this
    <span class="colored red">+3,00$</span>

Comment: The code blocks provided in my answer are to show what is *wrong*, the correct solution is the second snippet in your question itself. I have avoided posting it again and just explained why the other one doesn't work.

Comment: it didn't help . i look forward different way for solve it

Comment: @maviofis: Can you then clarify what output you are expecting (the compiled CSS)? I thought you already mentioned in your question that the second method works (which is the same as the recommended solution).

Comment: output must be like that : .colored.red, .colored.blue, .colored.gray

Comment: @maviofis: Did you see the code under the **Solution** part? It is the same as the second snippet in your question and that is the only possible solution :)